# python import swig library fails with dynamic module does not define init function

Tags: python, function, swig, init, shared

I've got a very simple example.c:

```
double My_variable = 3.0;
```

And a example_python.i:

```
%module example
%{
extern double My_variable;
%}
```

Then I run:

```
swig -python example_python.i
gcc -o example.o -c -fPIC example.c
gcc -o example_python.o -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -fPIC example_python_wrap.c
gcc -o libpython_lib.so -shared example.o example_python.os
```

OK, I run python:

```
>>> import libpython_lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initlibpython_lib)
>>>
```

So did I miss anything here? How to fix this issue? I am using SWIG Version 3.0.12 and ubuntu gcc version 7.3.0.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you tried to create the shared object with the name of the module name itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example_python.i file, you need the module name to match the name of the import module.

Swig will generate the init function from the module name. So you should be able to fix by changing the example_python.i to:

```
%module libpython_lib
%{
extern double My_variable;
%}
```

So when you import libpython_lib, it will find the module. Also you could change the import and shared library to be named 'example' as an alternate solution.